# PHP How to create folder into the aws s3 bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, directory, storage

please help me out! I'm using aws-php-sdk to uplaod a file on aws s3 server. I'm able to move the folder from our server to aws s3 server and can delete a file, but not able to create a directory/
    I always gets the access denied error.

The error is

```
Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/***/***/***/picture/"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://s3.amazonaws.com/***/****/****/picture/` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>CE24E8 (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>CE24E8FFC9216978</RequestId><HostId>DHdN6tcopPTP9IsVu/qGWClf1+hAoWv7CNUWJRsOPWia4SfQYQ+VPYgJ3+vlqqRBNbYWB34gEQ0=</HostId></Error>


and here is my code

  $s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
            'version' => AWS_VERSION,
            'region' => AWS_REGION,
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => AWS_KEY,
                'secret' =>AWS_SECRET,
            ],
        ]);


//code to create the directory

        $s3Client->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => AWS_BUCKET, // Defines name of Bucket
            'Key' => "picture/", //Defines Folder name
            'Body' => "",
            'ACL' => 'public-read' // Defines Permission to that folder
        ));

//I have also used along with full AWS_PATH, that is my uploading direcctory path on the aws server but none of them is working always gets the same error.

       $s3Client->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => AWS_BUCKET, // Defines name of Bucket
            'Key' => AWS_PATH . "picture/", //Defines Folder name
            'Body' => "",
            'ACL' => 'public-read' // Defines Permission to that folder
        ));
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution my self.
actually while creating a new directory, I can't give the permission to the new directory as i'm not the owner of the bucket. I was using the bucket as third party. So from the code I have to remove 'ACL'=>'public-read', now my code is

```
 $s3Client->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => AWS_BUCKET, // Defines name of Bucket
            'Key' => AWS_PATH . "picture/", //Defines Folder name
            'Body' => "",
        ));
```